# Group views in ConstraintLayout to treat them as a single view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

I need to apply some constraints to a group of views in [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html). I want to group these views and continue editing while the layout designer in Android studio treats them as a single view. Is there a way to do so without actually wrapping the views with a `ViewGroup` (another layout)? If such a wrapper is necessary, maybe there is a wrapper layout that comes with `ConstraintLayout` and allows to group objects without creating heavy layouts like `RelativeLayout`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

## ConstraintLayout  Chains

Android developers recently released a new version of [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) (**1.0.2** as of today). This version contains a new major feature - [Chains](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#Chains), which allows us to group views in [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html).

> Chains provide group-like behavior in a single axis (horizontally or vertically).
>
> A set of widgets are considered a chain if they a linked together via a bi-directional connection
>
> Once a chain is created, there are two possibilities:
>
> - Spread the elements in the available space
> - A chain can also be "packed", in that case the elements are grouped together

Currently, you need to use the following gradle dependency to use this feature (since it is an alpha):

```
 compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
```

[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) you may find the newest version of `ConstraintLayout` to use in your projects.

Until [Android Studio 2.3](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/androidstudio23canaryavailable), Android Studio user interface designer did not support creating chains since you couldn't add bi-directional constraints in it. The solution was to create these constraints in manually XML, as mentioned by [TranslucentCloud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2202101/translucentcloud). From Android Studio 2.3 (currently only on canary channel), chains are supported in a UI editor as well (as [GoRoS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812598/goros) mentioned in comments).

---

## Example

Following is an example of how to position two views together in the middle of a screen using `ConstraintLayout` and **chains**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainPacked="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

### Update (Jan, 2018) by [**@Mateus Gondim**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3752244/mateus-gondim)

In the recent versions, you should use `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"` instead of `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainPacked="true"`

---

Comment: Necessary to add, in Android Studio 2.2.2 there is no possibility to make bi-directional connections via User Interface Designer, thus they need to be specified directly in the XML resources.

Comment: However the new Android Studio 2.3 currently in canary channel does support chains in layout editor view http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio23canaryavailable

Comment: Nowadays you should use `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"` instead of `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainPacked="true"`. I'm on `constraint-layout:1.0.2'` version and the latter doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Not what he asked.

Comment: Note the key phrase "bi-directional connection". Only having a 1 way connection to the view above tripped me up for a minute.

Comment: Also I had to add the chainStyle attribute to both elements in my chain, not just one. EDIT: looks like nvm as long as you add it to the "first" element in the chain left to right (for horizontal) it works.

Answer (score 11):

You can use

```
android.support.constraint.Guideline
```

to group elements together.

Add a Guideline (vertical or horizontal) and then use that as an anchor for the other views. Here is a simple example of horizontally centering two grouped textviews: (showing design view in AS)

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/top_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:text="Above"
        tools:text="Above" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:text="Below"
        tools:text="Below" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Right vertically centered"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Right vertically centered"/>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: what if there are three textViews to be align vertically

Answer (score 8):

I just want to add some graphics to the great accepted answer.  It is very straightforward:

In layout design view > select all the views that you want to group > right-click them > Chains > Create Horizontal Chain:
[image]

It is also straightforward to center them:

Select the **head** view of the group > Organize > Pack Horizontally > set the start constraint of the first view and the end constraint of the last view to their parent:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use height **0dp** and **organize** views **vertically**.

in **relative layout** we can use layout below and above like

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        />
```

In constraint layout giving height is compulsory so you can give 0 height.
and then you can set your view below other views like this

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tablayout" />
```

you can use **constraintTop_toBottomOf** and **constraintBottom_toTopOf**  properties to adjust your view to above or below of other.
thanks

Comment: Although thats good information, i dont think its what the OP is asking.