# Center components in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am pretty sure that `ConstraintLayout` should not be used for use case described below, but, for sake of discussion, what would be the best way to center vertically aligned components in `ConstraintLayout` (as it is possible in `LinearLayout` with gravity set to "center" and vertical orientation) ?

It is possible to center single component by adding constraints to all four sides. It will position it perfectly in center of the screen. But if we have multiple components mutually constrained, then it starts to be tricky since all components will tend to overlap (if constrained to top and bottom, which is expected behavior) or newly added component will be below centered component (or above).

I have end-up with solution that does not feel to be perfect, by adding one component above, and one below to the centered component. That way components will be aligned vertically and almost centered :).

Here is an example:

1. Centered component:

[image: Centered component]

2. Component above, constrained to center

[image]

3. Component below, constrained to center

[image]

Other components placed above and below are constrained respectively to the nearest component (above or below).
As you can see on first image, components are not perfectly centered, because there are three components below and two components above "Country" field. 
Any designer will notice this :), so is it possible to use `ConstraintLayout` and to center whole group of components (or it is not meant to work like this)

P.S.
`LinearLayout` with `gravity="center"` is probably the best solution for this case.

Comment: a workaround maybe adding a dummy view such as  android.widget.Space which is centered in constraint layout if your view count is odd.

Comment: @DevrimTuncer yes, thats one possible workaround. Actually any view with invidible state could do it. There are positive news about this issue. You can check it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37598143/1274951. But until then :)

Comment: You could do it with a horizontal guide centered vertically and then build from there. Your use case is something we'd like to support in the future, probably by allowing the grouping of multiple views.

Comment: Thank you @RomainGuy, nice to hear that at first hand.